# SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR when update comment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want update a comment in Laravel.

```
<div class="edit-input" id="edit{{$comment->id}}">
   <input type="text" name="edit_comment" class="form-control">
   <div class="input-group-append">
       <a href="{{ route('review-edit', [ 'id' => $comment->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">OK</a>
       <button class="btn btn-danger" id="editCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

This my route:

```
Route::get('review-edit/{id}', 'CommentController@editComment')->name('review-edit');
```

And CommentController:

```
public function editComment(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $updateComment = Comment::findOrFail($id);
        $updateComment->user_id = Auth::id();
        $updateComment->comment = $request->edit_comment;
        $updateComment->save();
        return back();

    }
```

When I try update comment, I'm getting an error telling me

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7

dd($request->edit_comment) gives null also. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: make edit_comment field nullable or update with data . ref link http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-407_sqlstate_23502.html

Comment: comment column in comments table can't be nullable

Comment: $id coming or not ?

Comment: @Zon yes, $id coming

Comment: what is your form action path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
you `edit_comment` should be inside form then only you can send data to controller

```php
<form action="{{ route('review-edit', [ 'id' => $comment->id]) }}" method="get">
    <div class="edit-input" id="edit{{$comment->id}}">
       <input type="text" name="edit_comment" class="form-control">
       <div class="input-group-append">
           <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">OK</button>
           <button class="btn btn-danger" id="editCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and `dd($request->edit_comment);`

```
 <form action="{{ route('review-edit', [ 'id' => $comment->id]) }}" method="get">
    <div class="edit-input" id="edit{{$comment->id}}">
       <input type="text" name="edit_comment" class="form-control">
       <div class="input-group-append">
           <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">OK</button>
           <button class="btn btn-danger" id="editCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
       </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: it's not the final solution, but providing you a hint that where you are doing mistake, I think when you `dd($request);` in your `editComment`, you get `null` because you are not dispatching input request from the view